# How to get form values in ionic framework

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic2

My html is like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" novalidate class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched">
   <div id="pr1">
   </div>

   <div id="pr2">
   </div>

   <div class="bottom">
      <button class="btn info" ion-button (click)='factfind5();'> BACK </button>
      <button class="btn info" (click)='factfind71(this);' ion-button > NEXT </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Typescript file is like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { FactFind5Page } from '../factfind5/factfind5';
import { FactFind71Page } from '../factfind71/factfind71';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-factfind61',
  templateUrl: 'factfind61.html',
})
export class FactFind61Page {

form : FormGroup;
div1content : any;
div2content : any;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
}
factfind5(){
   this.navCtrl.setRoot(FactFind5Page);
}

factfind71(values){
  this.storeValuesToLocalStorage(values);
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(FactFind71Page);
}
storeValuesToLocalStorage(values){
   let array = {
     "AnnualIncomeNeeded":values.form.value.AnnualIncomeNeeded,
     "medicalneededamnt":values.form.value.medicalneededamnt
   }
  window.localStorage.setItem('CFF6Values', JSON.stringify(array));
}

this.div1content = "<ion-row class='row'><ion-col class='col'><ion-item class='item item-block item-md item-input item-label-stacked ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid'><div class='item-inner'><div class='input-wrapper'><ion-input class='input-text input input-md ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid' formcontrolname='AnnualIncomeNeeded' [(ngModel)]='AnnualIncomeNeeded' name='AnnualIncomeNeeded' type='text' (keypress)='AllowOnlyNumber($event)' ng-reflect-name='AnnualIncomeNeeded' ng-reflect-type='text'><input class='text-input text-input-md' dir='auto' ng-reflect-klass='text-input' ng-reflect-ng-class='text-input-md' type='text' aria-labelledby='lbl-79' autocomplete='off' autocorrect='off' placeholder='' formcontrolname='AnnualIncomeNeeded' ng-reflect-name='AnnualIncomeNeeded' ng-reflect-type='text'></ion-input></div></div>";

this.div2content = "<ion-row class='row'><ion-label class='potentialarealbl label label-md'>Medical / Healthcare Planning</ion-label></ion-row><ion-row class='row'><ion-col class='col'><ion-item class='item item-block item-md item-input item-label-stacked ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid'><div class='item-inner'><div class='input-wrapper'><ion-label class='input-label wraptext label label-md' stacked='' id='lbl-60'>Amount needed for treatment of Medical/ Hospitalisation (RM)</ion-label><ion-input class='input-text input input-md ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid' formcontrolname='medicalneededamnt' [(ngModel)]='medicalneededamnt' name='medicalneededamnt' (keypress)='AllowOnlyNumber($event)' type='text' ng-reflect-name='medicalneededamnt' ng-reflect-type='text'><input class='text-input text-input-md' dir='auto' ng-reflect-klass='text-input' ng-reflect-ng-class='text-input-md' type='text' aria-labelledby='lbl-60' autocomplete='off' autocorrect='off' placeholder='' formcontrolname='medicalneededamnt' ng-reflect-name='medicalneededamnt' ng-reflect-type='text'></ion-input></div></div><div class='button-effect'></div></ion-item></ion-col>";

   $('#pr1').append(this.div1content);
   $('#pr2').append(this.div2content);
  }

}
```

I append the html content in ts file. I need to get the input box values while pressing the NEXT button. The method `storeValuesToLocalStorage()` tries to access the input ngModel values but it couldn't. Is there any mistakes in my code while assigning and getting the values? Can you help?

Comment: where are you setting the form? is it reactive form? you can access from that

Comment: Also... `$('#pr1').append(this.div1content);` wont work.. since ionic component tags will be compiled before serving in the browser (unless this is ionic v4?)

Comment: I use ionic framework 3.9.2 This form loads as expected but only the values are not accessable.

Comment: what does `this.form.value` have? https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup

Comment: `this.form.value` is supposed to have the each form values I have declared in ngModel. But in my case, it does not have anything